# Unable to access shared preference inside Service - Android

Tags: android

Hi I am using the `GCMListener` service to listen to incoming messages. I am trying to access my shared preference in the service, with the help of [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo).

I get the following error when trying to access the shared preference.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.artqueen.aahaan.GCM.MyGcmListenerService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:184)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
            at com.artqueen.aahaan.Helper.TinyDB.<init>(TinyDB.java:31)
            at com.artqueen.aahaan.GCM.MyGcmListenerService.<init>(MyGcmListenerService.java:40)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3268)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1558)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6141)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

I am using the **GCMListenerService** like this

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(MyGcmListenerService.this);

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");

        String user = data.getString("user","");
        Log.e("user = "," "+user);

        ArrayList<String> blockList = tinyDB.getListString("blockList");


       if(blockList.contains(user)){
           //dont show notification
       }else {
           //show notification
           sendNotification(user);
       }
    }
```

And for your reference, the **TinyDB** class looks like this

```
public class TinyDB {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private String DEFAULT_APP_IMAGEDATA_DIRECTORY;
    private String lastImagePath = "";

    public TinyDB(Context appContext) {
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
    }


    /**
     * Decodes the Bitmap from 'path' and returns it
     * @param path image path
     * @return the Bitmap from 'path'
     */
    public Bitmap getImage(String path) {
        Bitmap bitmapFromPath = null;
        try {
            bitmapFromPath = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmapFromPath;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the String path of the last saved image
     * @return string path of the last saved image
     */
    public String getSavedImagePath() {
        return lastImagePath;
    }


    /**
     * Saves 'theBitmap' into folder 'theFolder' with the name 'theImageName'
     * @param theFolder the folder path dir you want to save it to e.g "DropBox/WorkImages"
     * @param theImageName the name you want to assign to the image file e.g "MeAtLunch.png"
     * @param theBitmap the image you want to save as a Bitmap
     * @return true if image was saved, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean putImage(String theFolder, String theImageName, Bitmap theBitmap) {
        if (theFolder == null || theImageName == null || theBitmap == null)
            return false;

        this.DEFAULT_APP_IMAGEDATA_DIRECTORY = theFolder;
        String mFullPath = setupFullPath(theImageName);

        if (!mFullPath.equals("")) {
            lastImagePath = mFullPath;
            return saveBitmap(mFullPath, theBitmap);
        }

        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Saves 'theBitmap' into 'fullPath'
     * @param fullPath full path of the image file e.g. "Images/MeAtLunch.png"
     * @param theBitmap the image you want to save as a Bitmap
     * @return true if image was saved, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean putImageWithFullPath(String fullPath, Bitmap theBitmap) {
        return !(fullPath == null || theBitmap == null) && saveBitmap(fullPath, theBitmap);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the path for the image with name 'imageName' in DEFAULT_APP.. directory
     * @param imageName name of the image
     * @return the full path of the image. If it failed to create directory, return empty string
     */
    private String setupFullPath(String imageName) {
        File mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), DEFAULT_APP_IMAGEDATA_DIRECTORY);

        if (isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable() && !mFolder.exists()) {
            if (!mFolder.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Failed to setup folder");
                return "";
            }
        }

        return mFolder.getPath() + '/' + imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the Bitmap as a PNG file at path 'fullPath'
     * @param fullPath path of the image file
     * @param bitmap the image as a Bitmap
     * @return true if it successfully saved, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean saveBitmap(String fullPath, Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (fullPath == null || bitmap == null)
            return false;

        boolean fileCreated = false;
        boolean bitmapCompressed = false;
        boolean streamClosed = false;

        File imageFile = new File(fullPath);

        if (imageFile.exists())
            if (!imageFile.delete())
                return false;

        try {
            fileCreated = imageFile.createNewFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmapCompressed = bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bitmapCompressed = false;

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    streamClosed = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    streamClosed = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return (fileCreated && bitmapCompressed && streamClosed);
    }

    // Getters

    /**
     * Get int value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If key not found, return 'defaultValue'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param defaultValue int value returned if key was not found
     * @return int value at 'key' or 'defaultValue' if key not found
     */
    public int getInt(String key, int defaultValue) {
        return preferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get parsed ArrayList of Integers from SharedPreferences at 'key'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @return ArrayList of Integers
     */
    public ArrayList<Integer> getListInt(String key) {
        String[] myList = TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚");
        ArrayList<String> arrayToList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myList));
        ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (String item : arrayToList)
            newList.add(Integer.parseInt(item));

        return newList;
    }

    /**
     * Get long value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If key not found, return 'defaultValue'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param defaultValue long value returned if key was not found
     * @return long value at 'key' or 'defaultValue' if key not found
     */
    public long getLong(String key, long defaultValue) {
        return preferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get float value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If key not found, return 'defaultValue'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param defaultValue float value returned if key was not found
     * @return float value at 'key' or 'defaultValue' if key not found
     */
    public float getFloat(String key, float defaultValue) {
        return preferences.getFloat(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get double value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If exception thrown, return 'defaultValue'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param defaultValue double value returned if exception is thrown
     * @return double value at 'key' or 'defaultValue' if exception is thrown
     */
    public double getDouble(String key, double defaultValue) {
        String number = getString(key);

        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(number);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get parsed ArrayList of Double from SharedPreferences at 'key'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @return ArrayList of Double
     */
    public ArrayList<Double> getListDouble(String key) {
        String[] myList = TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "â€šâ€—â€š");
        ArrayList<String> arrayToList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myList));
        ArrayList<Double> newList = new ArrayList<Double>();

        for (String item : arrayToList)
            newList.add(Double.parseDouble(item));

        return newList;
    }

    /**
     * Get String value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If key not found, return ""
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @return String value at 'key' or "" (empty String) if key not found
     */
    public String getString(String key) {
        return preferences.getString(key, "");
    }

    /**
     * Get parsed ArrayList of String from SharedPreferences at 'key'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @return ArrayList of String
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getListString(String key) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚")));
    }

    /**
     * Get boolean value from SharedPreferences at 'key'. If key not found, return 'defaultValue'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param defaultValue boolean value returned if key was not found
     * @return boolean value at 'key' or 'defaultValue' if key not found
     */
    public boolean getBoolean(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Get parsed ArrayList of Boolean from SharedPreferences at 'key'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @return ArrayList of Boolean
     */
    public ArrayList<Boolean> getListBoolean(String key) {
        ArrayList<String> myList = getListString(key);
        ArrayList<Boolean> newList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

        for (String item : myList) {
            if (item.equals("true")) {
                newList.add(true);
            } else {
                newList.add(false);
            }
        }

        return newList;
    }

    // Put methods

    /**
     * Put int value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value int value to be added
     */
    public void putInt(String key, int value) {
        preferences.edit().putInt(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put ArrayList of Integer into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param intList ArrayList of Integer to be added
     */
    public void putListInt(String key, ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
        Integer[] myIntList = intList.toArray(new Integer[intList.size()]);
        preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("‚‗‚", myIntList)).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put long value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value long value to be added
     */
    public void putLong(String key, long value) {
        preferences.edit().putLong(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put float value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value float value to be added
     */
    public void putFloat(String key, float value) {
        preferences.edit().putFloat(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put double value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value double value to be added
     */
    public void putDouble(String key, double value) {
        putString(key, String.valueOf(value));
    }

    /**
     * Put ArrayList of Double into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param doubleList ArrayList of Double to be added
     */
    public void putListDouble(String key, ArrayList<Double> doubleList) {
        Double[] myDoubleList = doubleList.toArray(new Double[doubleList.size()]);
        preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("â€šâ€—â€š", myDoubleList)).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put String value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value String value to be added
     */
    public void putString(String key, String value) {
        preferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put ArrayList of String into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param stringList ArrayList of String to be added
     */
    public void putListString(String key, ArrayList<String> stringList) {
        String[] myStringList = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
        preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("‚‗‚", myStringList)).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put boolean value into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param value boolean value to be added
     */
    public void putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
        preferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Put ArrayList of Boolean into SharedPreferences with 'key' and save
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     * @param boolList ArrayList of Boolean to be added
     */
    public void putListBoolean(String key, ArrayList<Boolean> boolList) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Boolean item : boolList) {
            if (item) {
                newList.add("true");
            } else {
                newList.add("false");
            }
        }

        putListString(key, newList);
    }


    /**
     * Remove SharedPreferences item with 'key'
     * @param key SharedPreferences key
     */
    public void remove(String key) {
        preferences.edit().remove(key).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Delete image file at 'path'
     * @param path path of image file
     * @return true if it successfully deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteImage(String path) {
        return new File(path).delete();
    }


    /**
     * Clear SharedPreferences (remove everything)
     */
    public void clear() {
        preferences.edit().clear().apply();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve all values from SharedPreferences. Do not modify collection return by method
     * @return a Map representing a list of key/value pairs from SharedPreferences
     */
    public Map<String, ?> getAll() {
        return preferences.getAll();
    }


    /**
     * Register SharedPreferences change listener
     * @param listener listener object of OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
     */
    public void registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {

        preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Unregister SharedPreferences change listener
     * @param listener listener object of OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to be unregistered
     */
    public void unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
            SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener) {

        preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
    }


    /**
     * Check if external storage is writable or not
     * @return true if writable, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    }

    /**
     * Check if external storage is readable or not
     * @return true if readable, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out why I am not able to access my shared preference inside the service. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used `getApplicationContext()`

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
```

in `Service` for accessing **context**

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.artqueen.aahaan.GCM.MyGcmListenerService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: @ShaikMDAshiq make sure you are instantiating it in onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably problem is not to call SharedPreferences  in right place. If we use a run thread (inside our Service class) we should call it inside it, or if you need it in your onCreate() then call it inside onCreate() method of your Service class

```
SharedPreferences shp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("sam", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
```